# Add [js] tag synonym for [javascript]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

I think it would be helpful to have a [js] tag that is a synomym of [javascript]. In Stack Overflow, this synonym exists, and I was initially confused when trying to  tag a question, thinking that there was no JavaScript tag, because I normally just type "js".

Could we add this as a synonym?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect we have kept on top of that to retag [js] to [javascript], but I like the idea of the synonym, especially since SO does the same thing.  I just made it.